# SSIS - Oracle view not visible to import

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS. I do not have access to oracle DB. Oracle team has created a view and granted access to that view to a user which we are using to connect to DB through SSIS.

1. When I  create a new ADO.NET connection and click on test connection ,it says connection is successful and when i try to retrieve the "tables or views" pop up box comes to enter password again and it throws error.Error : "Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager.Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
   Where as If i use the existing connection with same credentials it is working.What can be the possible reasons ?
2. However I used the existing connection and When I look for the view which is to be used as source, That view is not available.When I reached out to Oracle DB team who has created view , they say that the view exists and permission is granted to the user .They logged in to oracle using the same user and the user has access to the views.Now I am not sure  that why is it not available to the user when I connect it through SSIS. I am using visual studio 2017

Comment: It is possible that the user you mentioned only have access to that particular view (view table) and not the Oracle dictionary which is probably the one that Visual Studio or SISS is trying to use to access the list of tables. That is why the connection works but the "List tables or views" fails. Think like this, say your view name is "my_table" and oracle has a view called "user_views" (or something like that) if Oracle team did not gave permission to your user on "user_views" that is way it is failing.

Comment: Thanks Jorge.but I think you mixed both the questions as probably i couldn't make it clear. 1) I cannot create a new connection where as the old connection is working for the oracle database - credentials used were same.Now this is not related to the access to views as when I use the old connection i can see many tables but cannot see the one i need . What I know is they have created  a view say "my_table" and gave access to the view "my_table" to the user. now I can't access that oracle view "my_table" through SSIS but listing gives me list of other tables.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to pick ".Net Providers\OracleClient Data Provider" from the Provider list in Connection manager for ADO.NET. Second, You should enter the name of your Oracle DB or the IP of it (The name is better) for "Server name:" drop down. Third you should enter your user and password in the textboxes below the "Log on to the database". After all of these, you can click on "Test Connection" and everything goes right. now you can click "yes" to shut the window.

Now you can add one ADO.NET source in your data flow task, pick your connection in its "ADO.NET connection manager" drop down, and finally see the tables or views list in the "Name of the table or the view" drop down.